# npm script for docker

Tags: docker, package.json, npm-scripts

Trying to write an npm script for my project. I am using docker and i was trying simplify the application start commands. I don't want to use the docker compose command at this time.

I am trying to run the below command in npm script.

```
  "scripts": {
 "app-start" : "docker system prune && docker run -p 3000:3000 -v 
  /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app $(docker build -f Dockerfile.dev 
  .)"
   }
```

is there a way to provide parameter to docker run command using docker build, something like below:

```
 docker run -p 3000:3000 -v 
  /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app $(docker build -f Dockerfile.dev 
  .)
```

Also any improvements/ suggestions on the above commands

Comment: What parameter are you trying to provide? To which command? Do you need to pass a parameter to build or to run? You two code block seems the same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-q / --quiet switch`

```
Suppress the build output and print image ID on success
```

So your command will end with

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app $(docker build -q -f Dockerfile.dev .)
```